# What is a pop_up windows?

Tags: vim-windows, version

Vim 8.2 has been released a couple of days ago and as I was reading I see that you can display somehow functions prototype, I am pretty exciting about this I hope documentations come pretty soon, anyway the main feature within this update are pop-up windows. If a pop-up window its what I think it is: like a small window but with more volatile purpose, then when you writte something like [I or :reg the window that show-up wouldnt be already a pop-up window?
https://www.vim.org/vim-8.2-released.php

Extra: If you already know something about displaying function protoype that would be awesome.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Vi and Vim SE. This reads a bit like a forum post rather than a straightforward question. Would you edit it to make it cut-and-dry what you would like to know about popup windows? Also, questions should be about one topic. Regarding function prototypes, if you have a query about those please open another question. See https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask  Thanks.

Comment: To get a feeling of what this is, try leaderf with popup option on